# Why is my var_dump() only showing when used outside of the function?

Tags: php, wordpress, var-dump

I'm learning about `var_dump()` while trying to debug some code in my WordPress functions.php file.

When `var_dump()` is used inside a function it does not display on the page. Nothing will display with this:

```
function my_function() {
    $test_variable = 'some words';
    var_dump($test_variable);
}
```

But when `var_dump()` is outside of a function it displays fine. This displays the dump:

```
$test_variable = 'some words';
var_dump($test_variable);
```

Why is my `var_dump()` only showing when used outside of the function?

Comment: Do you _call_ the function?

Comment: where is function call?

Comment: Just figured that out! I feel a bit stupid now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not called function any where.

```
function my_function() {
    $test_variable = 'some words from inside my_function';
    var_dump($test_variable);
}

$test_variable = 'some words from out side my_function';
var_dump($test_variable);

my_function();
```

This show the both statement.